# Bootstrap/JQuery/HTML/CSS problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently redesigning a society's website for my university and I have a fair amount of web development experience but nothing too extensive.

Here is the current website: http://enactusreading.com/.

Here is the new one that I am designing: http://www.tech.nn.pe/.

So here are the current problems I've having:

- Using Bootstrap Carousel the next and previous arrow images aren't appearing which is strange...?
- How do you get the Facebook feed to be responsive?
- When resizing the page the image slider tucks underneath the navbar, not sure how to fix that one?
- Again when resizing the page there's whitespace around the example images I put on the page?

Just to clarify, I am not an expert especially when it comes to responsive web design. Any help will be greatly appreciated! :P

Answer (score 0):

> Using Bootstrap Carousel the next and previous arrow images aren't
>   appearing which is strange...?

Use the minified version of bootstrap and add glyphicons ( your website throws 2 404 erros:

```
http://www.tech.nn.pe/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://www.tech.nn.pe/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

> How do you get the Facebook feed to be responsive?

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/256568534516879/

> When resizing the page the image slider tucks underneath the navbar,
>   not sure how to fix that one?

Here's the example of navbar you should be using.
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

> Again when resizing the page there's whitespace around the example
>   images I put on the page?

The margin on the .img is set to auto. Try add a style with margin: 0

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply! So it turns out I just hadn't included the 'glyphicons' font files, my mistake :/

I'll look into the Facebook responsive activity feed a bit more.

When you say that this is the navbar I 'should' be using what do you mean by that? I mean I don't mind using that one, but I like how the current one I'm using spans across the entire sceen.

Just going to attempt the image margin corrections now! :)

Comment: For the navbar, please try and replace it with this example and see if it still flickers. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: The new navbar didn't make a difference, the image slider still disappears underneath the navbar when resizing and the margin corrections didn't work either. When changing the 'margin: auto;' to 'margin: 0;' it works on one side but not the other? :(

Comment: After extracting the image slider into a separate index file it appears as if its the image slider that isn't responsively resizing properly.